# Default ConfigModule instantiated twice

Tags: module, configuration, nestjs

When I launch the app my ConfigModule is instantiated twice also the ConfigHostModule which is never declared in my project, I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826790/nestjs-using-same-instance-of-service-in-multiple-modules) that help to understand better but don't know yet how to instantiate once my ConfigModule and NOT use ConfigHostModule, I have to declare ConfigModule in app.module because I use behind being required to send emails, so obviusly in others modules I'd like to use this same instance of ConfigModule so the app don't need to instantiate two times this Module

here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { APP_GUARD, APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MailModule } from '@enlazo/mail/dist';
import { CardsModule } from './cards/cards.module';
import { DatabaseModule } from '@enlazo/bd_ibm/dist';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { CustomersModule } from './customers/customers.module';
import { AtGuard } from './common/guards';
import { LogsInterceptor } from './common/interceptors/logs.interceptor';
import { LogsModule } from './log/logs.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CardsModule,
    CustomersModule,
    DatabaseModule,
    MailModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    AuthModule,
    LogsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AtGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: LogsInterceptor,
    },
    JwtService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

then I use ConfigService in some files inside AuthModule from ConfigModule inside my auth files, authService like this:

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { JwtPayload } from '../types';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { CodeResponse, ErrorResponse } from 'src/common/dto/baseResponse';

@Injectable()
export class AtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
    constructor(config: ConfigService) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Enlazo'),
            secretOrKey: config.get<string>('AT_SECRET'),
        });
    }

    validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
        //const accessToken = req?.get('authorization')?.replace('Enlazo', '').trim();
        if (!payload) throw new HttpException(new ErrorResponse(null, new CodeResponse({ code: "E000", message: "Access token not valid" })), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);

        return payload;
    }
}
```

Finally my Auth module looks like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UsersModule } from 'src/users/users.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AtStrategy, RtStrategy } from './strategies';


@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({}),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, AtStrategy, RtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Don't know if declaring something in Authmodule will force to use the same instance from app.Module.
the result of this code is like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you end up having `ConfigModule` in two `imports` arrays?

Comment: In the whole project I only have it in app.module the. I don't know if it count to have it in the test.spec.ts files...I don't think so. I use `ConfigService` in my `AuthModule` there is where I think nestjs reimport the `ConfigModule`